# is it possible in flutter to manage an upload session in the background activity?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner in flutter development and I need little help from you people. I want to manage an upload session in the background activity so every screen and every instance should know it's progress . I want make it just like Instagram when you upload a video, shows the progress bar in the home screen but when you change the screen it always store/ remember the progress of upload session and when you again comes to the home screen you still see the progress of upload session.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it's state. With GetX is simple, on upload controller you create progress var then on homepage just check it, while you update it via upload() method.

https://pub.dev/packages/get

Here is Tadas tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNpXbeI_slw&t=544s